# Rails validation - maximum database entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a rails project, using active record and was wondering if there was a validation helper for max number of individual entries. For example, if you had a form submission and only wanted, say 2, and you just wanted the first 2 to be persisted to the table, how would you do this?

I have read the manual and had a look at numericality etc but it's not really what I'm looking for. I have tried to write my own validation method in the model, but I am assuming there is a validation helper that makes this easier:

```
  def validatePassengerNumber 
    if self.passengers.length > 2
      # unsure on how to refuse new data access to database
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an error to base after check return true, and it will prohibit to save into database.

```
 def validate_passenger_number        
     self.errors.add(:base, "exceed maximum entry") if self.passengers.length > 2
 end
```

Call this custom validation in respective model.

```
  validate :validate_passenger_number, on: :create
```

Comment: Rails always uses **Snake Style** to name methods, like `validate_passenger_number`, instead of `validatePassengerNumber`!

Comment: Yes it should be as convention, just copied form question, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have placed this code into the model but it's still  saving to the database:

     validate :validate_passenger_number, on: :create

      def validate_passenger_number        
         self.errors.add(:base, "exceed maximum entry") if       self.passengers.length > 2
     end

Comment: @user3927582 this should prohibit to save a record when create a new record.

Comment: Thanks! Managed to get it working thanks - had a typo! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in validation; at least I haven't come across any. But following is a way to impose this type of validation:

```
  def max_passengers
    if self.passengers.count > 2
      errors.add_to_base("There should not be more than 2 passengers.")
    end
  end
```

And then, you can use this validation to impose a check on the number of passengers.

Answer (score 1):

You can add callback and validate the record.

```
before_validation :validate_passanger_number

private

def validate_passanger_number
  errors.add("Sorry", "you have added maximum passengers.") if self.passengers.count > 2
end
```